# Convert 1d array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a pretty simple problem, but for now, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I have a 1D array, for example:

```
$array = array("file", "video", "url")
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
$array["file"]["video"]["url"] = array();
```

Now, I won't know in advance how many elements I will have in my first array so I cannot make any assumptions. Also, I cannot use a tree structure for this particular problem, it needs to be an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly straightforward to build

```
$array = array("file", "video", "url");

$newArray = array();
$newEntry = &$newArray;
foreach($array as $value) {
    $newEntry[$value] = array();
    $newEntry = &$newEntry[$value];
}
unset($newEntry);
var_dump($newArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

Elegantly, using recursion

```
function nested($keys, $value) {
    return $keys ?
        array($keys[0] => nested(array_slice($keys, 1), $value))
        : $value;
}

print_r(nested(array("file", "video", "url"), 42));
```

Comment: Ahhh 42, the value to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything... :)